# Set time to synchronized via command line in ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, command-line

Below is an image that shows how to set the time automatically from Internet via GUI

[image]

I'm trying to write a bash scripts that sets the time the same way as if one does this via GUI

However, I cannot find the proper command line that does so.

thanks in advance

Comment: @Roadowl. I'm doing self learning. I found some commands like `sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z"`. However, i don't have to say what i'm doing. I believe this site is there when someone gets stuck!

Comment: This question would be a better fit for [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) imo as this is not really a question about programming

Comment: @Roadowl no need to be aggressive. Knowing which specific command is called under the hood by a GUI program is not that trivial

Comment: @Aserre. You're write. Thanks alot. The answer from MichielB also seems to be helpful. Shall i move the question to adsubuntu?

Comment: If the answer from MichielB solves your problem, you can just accept it. Otherwise, ask a new question on AskUbuntu

Comment: @Aserre. Thank you i found the answer in the link from michielB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out `timedatectl`, which is the systemd standard way to configure the time zone and time server. Documentation is below:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timedatectl.html

Comment: Thank you alot. This is what i call self-learning, However with Expert's help ^ ^.